# Are there two distributions whose product equals a gaussian?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

Are there two distributions $X$ and $Y$ over $\mathbb{R}$ such that the distribution of the product $XY$ follows a Gaussian distribution?

Comment: Have $X$ having a half-normal distribution (or indeed a normal distribution) with mode $0$ and independently $Y=\pm1$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are both standard normal then $X^2 + Y^2 \sim \chi^2_2 =
 \mathcal{E}(1/2)$ and the angle of $(X,Y)$ in the plane whose sinus is given by $\frac{Y}{\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}}$ is $\mathcal{U}_{[-\pi,\pi]}$.

Thus let $\theta \sim \mathcal{U}_{[-\pi,\pi]}$ and $Z \sim \mathcal{E}(1/2)$, then

$$
Y = \sqrt{Z} \text{sin}(\theta) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)
$$

where $\sqrt{Z}$ follows a [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution) with scale 1 while $\text{sin}(\theta)$ follows the [Arcsine distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_distribution).

This method is known as the [Box-Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) which enables one to generate standard normal variable from independent uniform variables.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will check that Box-Muller transform. If you know other ways to generate Gaussian distributions as products of other (non-trivial) distribution, please, let some links here. I am accepting  and upvoting. Thank you again.